# Why Swift doesn't let me put objects inside an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I was trying to create an array and then put objects inside it, but it gives me an error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

A Fragment of my code:

```
import UIKit
import HTPressableButton

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var lblAnswer: UILabel!

  var firstOption:HTPressableButton!
  var secondOption:HTPressableButton!
  var thirdOption:HTPressableButton!
  var fourthOption:HTPressableButton!


  var optionButtons:[HTPressableButton] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


      //Declaration of Width and Height to avoid calculate this value in each button.
      BUTTON_WIDTH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-210;
      BUTTON_HEIGHT = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-240;


      optionButtons[0] = firstOption
      optionButtons[1] = secondOption
      optionButtons[2] = thirdOption
      optionButtons[3] = fourthOption

      lblAnswer.font = UIFont(name: lblAnswer.font.fontName, size: (lblAnswer.font?.pointSize)!)
    }
```

}

It stops in `optionButtons[0] = firstOption` I've tried to change it for

```
optionButtons[0] = HTPressableButton(frame: firstFrameOp, buttonStyle: HTPressableButtonStyle.Rect)//firstOption
```

but it gives me a different error: `fatal error: Index out of range`

any help?

Comment: use **optionButtions.append(firstOption)** instead. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Also, firstOption is nil

Answer (score 3):

The crash happens because you're trying to access an index in the array that doesn't exist.

You can simply enter the buttons into the array with `append(Element)` or by setting the array as such:

```
optionButtons = [firstOption, secondOption, thirdOption, fourthOption]
```

Comment: @ xoudini I guess we both answered at the same time almost. Sorry, your answer is great as a short version. I'm voting you up :)

Answer (score 1):

You're just initializing the buttons in a wrong way. You created an empty array and then you're trying to access the items inside it but it's empty. You have to create the buttons and then add them to the array.
Cheers :)

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var lblAnswer: UILabel!

  var firstOption:HTPressableButton!
  var secondOption:HTPressableButton!
  var thirdOption:HTPressableButton!
  var fourthOption:HTPressableButton!


  var optionButtons:[HTPressableButton] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


      //Declaration of Width and Height to avoid calculate this value in each button.
      BUTTON_WIDTH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-210;
      BUTTON_HEIGHT = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-240;


      optionButtons_0 = HTPressableButton(frame: firstFrameOp, buttonStyle: HTPressableButtonStyle.Rect) //firstOption
      optionButtons_1 = HTPressableButton(frame: secondFrame, buttonStyle: HTPressableButtonStyle.Rect) 
      optionButtons_2 = HTPressableButton(frame: thirdFrame, buttonStyle: HTPressableButtonStyle.Rect) 
      optionButtons_3 = HTPressableButton(frame: fourthFrame, buttonStyle: HTPressableButtonStyle.Rect) 

      // lblAnswer.font = UIFont(name: lblAnswer.font.fontName, size: (lblAnswer.font?.pointSize)!)

       optionButtons.append(optionButtons_0, optionButtons_1, optionButtons_2, optionButtons_3)
    }
```